# How to customize the theme colors in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The `graphQL` and `apollo` is OK.

The typescript `AllColors.ts` is:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export const ALL_COLORS = gql`
    query allColors {
        allColors {
            primary
            secondary
        }
    }
`
```

I've tried this in `plugin/vuetify.ts` but doesn't walk.

```
import   Vue          from 'vue';
import   Vuetify      from 'vuetify/lib/framework';
import   colors       from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors';
import { ALL_COLORS } from '@/graphql/AllColors'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  data() {
    return {
      allColors: []
    }
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      dark: {
        primary:    this.allColors.primary,
        secondary:  this.allColors.secondary
      },
    },
  },
  apollo: {
    allColors: {
      query: ALL_COLORS
    }
  }
});
```

Gives this error:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 240ms                                                                              12:54:25

Type checking in progress...

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.0.102:8080/

ERROR in /home/user1/sites/app1/src/plugins/vuetify.ts(24,19):
26:19 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
    24 |         primary: this.allColors.primary,
       |                       ^
    25 |         secondary: this.allColors.secondary
    26 |       },
    27 |     },
    28 |   },

ERROR in /home/user1/sites/app1/src/plugins/vuetify.ts(25,21):
26:19 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
    24 |         primary: this.allColors.primary,
    25 |         secondary: this.allColors.secondary
       |                         ^
    26 |       },
    27 |     },
    28 |   },
Version: typescript 3.9.7
Time: 313ms
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're conflating the `Vue` constructor and the `Vuetify` constructor. Only the former has `data()` for creating local reactive properties, and the `apollo` property for `vue-apollo`.

To correct the issue:

1. In `@/plugins/vuetify.ts`, remove `data()` and `apollo` from the `Vuetify` constructor options, and move `apollo` to the `Vue` constructor in `main.ts`.
2. Move `allColors` to the top level before creating the `Vuetify` instance with the theme setting.

```js
// @/plugins/vuetify.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const allColors = {
  primary: '#1976D2',
  secondary: '#424242',
}

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      dark: {
        primary:   allColors.primary,
        secondary: allColors.secondary
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```js
// main.ts
import Vue            from 'vue';
import vuetify        from '@/plugins/vuetify';
import { ALL_COLORS } from '@/graphql/AllColors'

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  apollo: {
    allColors: {
      query: ALL_COLORS
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: And if you're using light theme, remember to change them as well

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify does not like the way you call allColors since it does not recognize the variables:
I assume that within the API call the primary and secondary colors are defined. Then you would still need to specify the path to them. How are the colors stored in vuetify? Because it looks like the variable path is incomplete, so it could be more like this: `this.apollo.AllColors.query.response.data.primary` (you might not need to say response.data)
[SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#nuxt-install) could help you store the color variables.